# SharePoint, Workflow and Web Services - restart workflow

Tags: .net, web-services, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-api

Can you restart a workflow or push a workflow to its next step using SharePoint Web Services?

If so which web service do you use? If you change a field like "Status" and the workflow uses this to know what it should do next... will it "nudge" the workflow forward?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, there is not a web service that will allow you to alter a workflow ITSELF in this way. ([list of the out of the box web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390.aspx))

The only way I can think of you would do this is:

1. Set up your workflow to wait for a value in a certain field to change
2. Update the list item the workflow is running on and set the value (will use the Lists.asmx web service)